# 404 error Additionally 403 Forbidden error on a URL

Tags: htaccess, 404-error, mod-rewrite

On my WordPress website i got a error on www.example.com/blog url only as the screenshot.

[image: Error]

I already check-

1. Files + Directory permission, everything is right.
2. Code on .htaccess, just WP default code there.
3. Change/Re-generate permalink.
4. Also on the domain root there is no directory with name "blog".

Comment: does that page exists?

Comment: Yes, problem with "blog" url only, working fine if i change permalink of that page to "blogs".